# Maven process killed after 5 minutes

Tags: java, bash, maven, cron

I have a maven project for which I needed to executed (using maven exec plugin) every day along with some simple operation in database. So I wrote an script for this process and wrote a cron job for this.

```
LAST_PAGE=$(mysql -hlocalhost -uuser -ppassword -DDB -e 'SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE LIMIT 1\G' | grep 'COLUMN_1')

CURRENT_PAGE=$((30 + $LAST_PAGE))

if [[ $CURRENT_PAGE -ge 270 ]]; then
        exit
fi

cd ~/workspace/datasaver/
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.datasaver.app.CollectionApp" -Dexec.cleanupDaemonThreads=false -Dexec.args="$LAST_PAGE" &


mysql -hlocalhost -uuser -ppassword -DDB -e "INSERT INTO SOME_TABLE(COLUMN_1) VALUES($CURRENT_PAGE)"
```

Maven target is expected to take more than 20 minutes, so I have added `&` to send it into background. I have edited `crontab` and have added
`0 0 * * * ~/runapp.sh` where `runapp.sh` is my bash file.

Now the problem is that my maven is terminated (probably killed) after 4 minutes every time. Cron logs show nothing at all regarding.
Any help appreciated.

I have redirected all maven and my own application logs to a log file `Application.log` and the last log I can see there is

```
00:04:55 [ERROR] [com.service.FollowService] - Error: no specified property identifier - Error Code: 5
```

Comment: You could redirect the output of mvn to a file to see where it stops

Comment: @assylias I have added more info in question

Comment: Do you have something important in your .profile or .bashrc?

Comment: @Walter No. Both of them are stock.

Comment: You can try `mvn .... "$LAST_PAGE" > /dev/null 2>&1 &` or remove & (deadlock with mysql on the next line?)